# Go , Update API method with GIN

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm newbie golang. I'm rearching and learning GIN to build restful API.

I'm having a hard time dealing with the Update Gin API method. Specifically, the part that stores the input data of the "email", "name" field.

The question is : How do I modify the json map[string]interface data to be able to save the data in. Hope everyone can help.
Thank you very much.

```
 func (r *UserRepo) UpdateInfoUser(id uint64) (*entity.User, error) {
    var user entity.User
    err := r.db.Debug().Where("id = ?", id).Take(&user).UpdateColumns(map[string]interface{}{
        "name":       // code here,
        "email":       // code here,
        "updated_at": time.Now(),
    }).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "// code here"?

Comment: yarh, this is my solution.
`func (r *UserRepo) UpdateInfoUser(id uint64, u *entity.User) (*entity.User, error) {
 var user entity.User
 err := r.db.Debug().Where("id = ?", id).Take(&user).UpdateColumns(map[string]interface{}{
  "name":       u.Name, 
  "updated_at": time.Now(),
 }).Error
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 return &user, nil
}`

Answer (score 1):

you should add two more function inputs.
try

```
 func (r *UserRepo) UpdateInfoUser(id uint64, name string, email string) (*entity.User, error) {
    var user entity.User
    err := r.db.Debug().Where("id = ?", id).Take(&user).UpdateColumns(map[string]interface{}{
        "name":       name,
        "email":      email,
        "updated_at": time.Now(),
    }).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your example solution, but this is my solution. 

`func (r *UserRepo) UpdateInfoUser(id uint64, u *entity.User) (*entity.User, error) {
 var user entity.User
 err := r.db.Debug().Where("id = ?", id).Take(&user).UpdateColumns(map[string]interface{}{
  "name":       u.Name, 
  "updated_at": time.Now(),
 }).Error
 if err != nil {
  return nil, err
 }
 return &user, nil
}`